# C#.net, Windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

Im trying a to post an url in windows phone 8. But the url is too large so im not able to make the request itself. So can you people help me out in this regard. Here im giving the sample URl

> http://192.168.1.59:8080/mno/customer/registerMobileWallet?d=%7b%22customer_FirstName%22%3a%22tw%22%2c%22customer_LastName%22%3a%22atat%22%2c%22customer_MobileNumber%22%3a%2261616161%22%2c%22customer_Email%22%3a%22ahah%40gmail.com%22%2c%22customer_Civil_Id%22%3a%22yaau%22%2c%22Civil_ID_Image_Front%22%3a%22%2f9j%2f4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2f2wBDAAYEBAUEBAYFBQUGBgYHCQ4JCQgICRINDQoOFRIWFhUSFBQXGiEcFxgfGRQUHScdHyIjJSUlFhwpLCgkKyEkJST%2f2wBDAQYGBgkICREJCREkGBQYJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCT%2fwAARCAAoACgDASIAAhEBAxEB%2f8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2f8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2bTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2bPn6%2f8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2f8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2bPn6%2f9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwDzFbeNMZIGOmaaREpGWXaOxNe8W2htsTybJtv3VKodvpjPTA6UX9jFpMYl1Sey06IsqCW4cIhY5wA3c8E%2bwGTxWsZzlrGJm4xW7PDm07Up7U%2bXYXEiEKyt9mLMcDAw2M4x26f0rarpFxKYJF0O5jRRh0t4pct6klt2Dzjpjjp1r3S3TRL%2bRbS18TaLdXLKSkMF4jlsDJxg56Ak8djT5vDFzg4h3oWKhojvAIPPTp360pxqpX5QXJ3PlPUbCyjuLhTLNaziRmSGZVdVj2lgDIuP3mcLjYBnrtwQCvY9R%2bDT2sr3ml3tzDqJdpBdXXzMX2nhSMbTubO7BYEKRtIOSsfaRW5VmY%2f%2fAAlHjvxFcI8Ooav%2b%2fZkQWrtbwyNgkgBNqljgnpk%2b9X2%2bEmvsyNZ6bbR%2fZZVklupVLs%2bOW2xH5WjHZSpZiDnqVXuJNclsIvs0l7BHbc7rOwj2jO5j80n3jkEA567fc5yNR1yG4u2uWVHdgR%2b%2bO%2fGevB4Gc%2bnNazxEPN%2f18x0sPKT7FCH4W2UbXlvfeLnnjuis0keiwb45gvRXijGxCDvCtkjnoMfN6RYXM%2bj6dJY6Rb3UisQyS6tcNJ5eRyNoySvbbkeua4P%2fAITO9hb5ZIyF6DaOOP8A9Vbej%2bPre%2fdbW%2b2wyNwr%2fwALegNZfXJR%2bDQ6JYSyu9TeZb2cMbm8eZSeihVwOMA9zgDAPu3rXKtXZCZcqN4K4xkdOf8AP%2be5XLOcpu8mZqy0SPn1%2fEMnRX7Zzmqtxr7seZWJPYHofWvWrii4qGdkHY8bbXJJCcMcZ6elOTW5C6hWIYkYIr2JKEosU5s0%2fC929%2foNrJIw3sg5%2fCszwvR4Xo8L04rQ86Unc%2f%2fZ%22%2c%22Civil_ID_Image_Back%22%3a%22%2f9j%2f4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD%2f2wBDAAYEBAUEBAYFBQUGBgYHCQ4JCQgICRINDQoOFRIWFhUSFBQXGiEcFxgfGRQUHScdHyIjJSUlFhwpLCgkKyEkJST%2f2wBDAQYGBgkICREJCREkGBQYJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCQkJCT%2fwAARCAAoACgDASIAAhEBAxEB%2f8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2f8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4%2bTl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3%2bPn6%2f8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL%2f8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3%2bPn6%2f9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD5zjtxFI42yMSo2bge468dv8auWkbFGLBC2edmMDgccVtQadAdEm1OSH7PJE6W9vgZF0%2fLPuz2UFckHA3ICp3lhXt4t6DPBOOSefQD8AB%2fngUtCLFFoSP4ccdKhZDnOOfrW2bLC4x%2bPUmprXw5fagR9ms5pQxxvVTtB%2f3jx%2btDkkJRMKzjY3CFCqhm2t0ztIIOPwzz29q9%2bs681074aalJIsty32YAcBGBbOeOxGPxr0rTqXtEWoMt6l8HNK1goyS3FuIYRDFHEwMaAZPAI45JJwRkkk8sSU0T9n%2b2tmY32ozTnIwIUWMfQ%2feP5Yr1uIT3crTXBMsjtuLFuntx2x%2blbNhEiBg%2fuo44zxx1Ht%2bdcUq1mdMYRtqefaZ8JtEsAXh0yHqGDuC7ZHoWyRz6cVqTeD%2fLGFRd3QA9z%2fkV6CsUaAIF5GG4GKdJbloiDFycrjOc9fT%2fACKn2rZT5djyu58MkKSAV4HUAV5%2fc171f24jB8xwNo%2bXoc9uM%2fT%2fAD3KpVDN7mfbOsaqPNGc8sW4I9P8ir0OowrCBHtCuCTtJUE56Yzj0%2fXrXg8NENYzQon0LFq8krKyoiqvBDHd%2fLp1qUzyOylpW2hjjnB%2fP06186mg1A72PfL4RqpyRnJ6nhu30rwO%2bovqL6rRDkz%2f2Q%3d%3d%22%2c%22language%22%3a%22English%22%2c%22Device_ID_number%22%3a%22f43kKcjK%2fWsN1r6ak49HmQFkB74%3d%22%2c%22g_transType%22%3a%22REGISTER%22%7d
>   ...

Comment: The solution would be to use a `POST` request and put your JSON in the request body instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way than change your request from providing parameters in URL to the body of POST request which does not has limit length.